# Overleaf track changes user mention and notification

Tags: overleaf

Regarding the track changes functionality of Overleaf and specifically comments, is it  possible to add user annotations, so that the user gets a notification to check a new comment?

For example, to do comments like the following "@[user] This sentence requires a citation", such that [user] gets a notification via email that there is a comment that concerns him/her.

Comment: check the best answer in this link: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/598/when-writing-a-comment-how-do-i-ensure-that-the-person-it-is-addressed-to-gets

Comment: @MashaMasha you linked a question that has nothing to do with the OP's question. They ask here about the OVERLEAF platform, and you linked to a discussion about the SO platform.